# Query AD Users from date

Tags: active-directory, powershell

How can I query users in AD that have been added since an specific date and that their user logon name starts with UTX ?
Im guessing I need to do it with powershell but I have very  little knowledge.
Can someone guide me a little? Thanks.

Comment: You need to put forth a little effort. Google. TRY. Make an attempt at a solution, then explain what problems you've encountered.

Answer (score 1):

I use this script. You can easily add in another filter for samaccountname.

```
$month = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=NFD,OU=US,DC=americas,DC=ad,DC=flextronics,DC=com" -searchscope onelevel -Properties * | where { $_.whenCreated -ge $month } | select SamAccountName,Name,whenCreated | sort whenCreated
```